# how to manage webview accordingly?

Tags: javascript, android

Actually, I have converted WordPress site into an android app. In WordPress site there is some add available on the site which is created in javascript, and when data is fetched into the android app as a webview, there is some space is shown in place of that ads. I want to remove it or want to add AdMob ads there. How could it be possible? Please help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance.
My Code is

```
public class PostViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = PostViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_POST_ID = "post_id";
    public static final String TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE = "post_title";
    public static final String TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE = "post_image";
    private String commentsNumber;


    private String selectedPostID, selectedPostTitle;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private ImageButton fab;
    private TextView post_name;
    private TextView post_content;
    private TextView post_author;
    private ImageView postImageView;
    private String post_image, objURL, objTitle;
    private Integer commentsCount;
    private TextView timestamp;
    private NetworkImageView profilePic;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    private WebView post_contentHTML;
    private Boolean user_can_comment = true;

    private Spanned spannedContent;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;
    private LinearLayout llayout;

    private Integer OC = 0;

    //----------Exit and Banner Ad----------------------------------
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private AdView mAdView;

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    public static void navigate(AppCompatActivity activity, View transitionImage, Post post) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PostViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE, post.getImge());
        intent.putExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE, post.getName());

        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, transitionImage, TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE);
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
        // killed and restarted.
        savedInstanceState.putString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID, selectedPostID);
        savedInstanceState.putString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE, selectedPostTitle);
        Log.d(TAG, savedInstanceState.toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Restored: " + savedInstanceState.toString());
        selectedPostID = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
        selectedPostTitle = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
        if (Const.Analytics_ACTIVE) {
            AnalyticsUtil.sendScreenName(this, TAG);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initActivityTransitions();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_view);

        //Forcing RTL Layout, If Supports and Enabled from Const file
        Utils.forceRTLIfSupported(this);

        ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(this);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        //Get and Set the Post Title
        String itemTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml(itemTitle));

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
                selectedPostID = null;
                selectedPostTitle = "Unknown Error";
            } else {
                selectedPostID = getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
                selectedPostTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Resume: " + savedInstanceState.toString());
            selectedPostID = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
            selectedPostTitle = (String) savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);
            /*selectedPostID = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(TAG_SEL_POST_ID);
            selectedPostTitle = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE);*/

        }

        //Setting up Fields Display
        fab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        post_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        timestamp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GenR102.ttf");
        post_name.setTypeface(font);


        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int leftPadding = (int) (20 * density);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(post_name) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            //post_name.setPadding(leftPadding,R.dimen.spacing_large,0,0);
            post_name.setPadding(leftPadding, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            post_name.setPadding(0, 0, leftPadding, 0);
        }


        post_content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        post_contentHTML = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionHTML);
        if (!Const.ShowPostAsWebView) {

            post_content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            Typeface font_postcontent = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OSRegular.ttf");
            post_content.setTypeface(font_postcontent);
        } else {
            post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            WebSettings webSettings = post_contentHTML.getSettings();
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
            post_contentHTML.addJavascriptInterface(this, "asiannews");
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            post_contentHTML.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            post_contentHTML.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            post_contentHTML.addJavascriptInterface(this, "AsianNews");
            post_contentHTML.loadUrl("javascript:Android.getIds(Ids);");
            post_contentHTML.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            //post_contentHTML.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.asiannews.co.in/bp4a-api/v1/post/_STORY_ID_/", myString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        }

        post_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);


        postImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        profilePic = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);


        //Setting up Post Image and Toolbar Activity
        //final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        /*ViewCompat.setTransitionName(postImageView, TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) postImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                applyPalette(palette, postImageView);
            }
        });*/


        //Setting Up Post Admob Banner
        ////Standard Banner
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        if (Const.ADMOBService_ACTIVE) {
            //----------Exit Ad----------------------------------
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.unit_id_interstitial));
            AdRequest adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(Const.ADMOB_DEVICE_ID).build();
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequestInterstitial);
            //----------Exit Ad----------------------------------

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(Const.ADMOB_DEVICE_ID).build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        getPost();

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void initActivityTransitions() {
        if (Utils.isLollipop()) {
            Slide transition = new Slide();
            transition.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(transition);
            getWindow().setReturnTransition(transition);
        }
    }

    private void applyPalette(Palette palette, ImageView image) {
        int primaryDark = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark);
        int primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(primary);
        Utils.setStatusBarcolor(getWindow(), primaryDark);
        initScrollFade(image);
        ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(this);
    }

    private void initScrollFade(final ImageView image) {
        final View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);

        setComponentsStatus(scrollView, image);

        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                setComponentsStatus(scrollView, image);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setComponentsStatus(View scrollView, ImageView image) {
        int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
        image.setTranslationY(-scrollY / 2);
        ColorDrawable background = (ColorDrawable) toolbar.getBackground();
        int padding = scrollView.getPaddingTop();
        double alpha = (1 - (((double) padding - (double) scrollY) / (double) padding)) * 255.0;
        alpha = alpha < 0 ? 0 : alpha;
        alpha = alpha > 255 ? 255 : alpha;

        background.setAlpha((int) alpha);

        float scrollRatio = (float) (alpha / 255f);
        int titleColor = getAlphaColor(Color.WHITE, scrollRatio);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(titleColor);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(titleColor);
    }

    private int getAlphaColor(int color, float scrollRatio) {
        return Color.argb((int) (scrollRatio * 255f), Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * It seems that the ActionBar view is reused between activities. Changes need to be reverted,
     * or the ActionBar will be transparent when we go back to Main Activity
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void restablishActionBar() {
        if (Utils.isLollipop()) {
            getWindow().getReturnTransition().addListener(new TransitionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        restablishActionBar();
        if (Const.ADMOBService_ACTIVE) {
            displayInterstitial();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            restablishActionBar();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void getPost() {
        //Requesting The Story
        String url = null;
        url = Const.URL_STORY_PAGE.replace("_STORY_ID_", selectedPostID.replace("P", ""));
        //Log.i(TAG, "Taging: " + url);
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "Taging: " + response.toString());
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        if (response.has("error")) {
                            String error = response.getString("error");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException es) {
                        es.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), es.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            /** Passing some request headers **/
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("ApiKey", Const.AuthenticationKey);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }


    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject feedObj) {
        try {
            objTitle = feedObj.getString("name");
            post_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(objTitle));

            commentsCount = feedObj.getInt("comments");
            if (feedObj.getString("can_comment") == "no") {
                user_can_comment = false;
            }

            if (!Const.ShowPostAsWebView) {
                post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(this, post_content);
                spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(feedObj.getString("story_content"), p, null);
                post_content.setText(trimTrailingWhitespace(spannedContent));
            } else {

                post_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                String post_con = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                        "<html lang=\"en\">" +
                        "  <head>" +
                        "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
                        "  </head>" +
                        "  <body>" +
                        "    #content# " +
                        "  </body>" +
                        "</html>";
                try {
                    InputStream in_s = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.post_format);
                    byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
                    in_s.read(b);
                    post_con = new String(b);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                post_con = post_con.replace("#title#", feedObj.getString("name"));
                post_con = post_con.replace("#content#", feedObj.getString("story_content"));
                //post_contentHTML.loadData(post_con, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
                post_contentHTML.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,
                        post_con,
                        "text/html",
                        "UTF-8",
                        null);
            }

            if (feedObj.getString("story_content").length() <= 0) {
                post_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                post_contentHTML.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            post_author.setText(feedObj.getString("author"));
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("By " + feedObj.getString("author"));

            post_image = feedObj.getString("image");
            objURL = feedObj.getString("url");

            if (Const.Analytics_ACTIVE) {
                AnalyticsUtil.sendEvent(this, "Post View", objTitle, objURL);
            }

            //Setting Up a Share Intent
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, objTitle + " - " + objURL);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"), 300);
                }
            });

            //setShareIntent(shareIntent);

            //Comment Button Click
            Button viewComments = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewComments);
            commentsNumber = Utils.formatNumber(commentsCount);
            viewComments.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.comments_button), commentsNumber));
            viewComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(PostViewActivity.this, PostComments.class);
                    i.putExtra("post_id", selectedPostID.replace("P", ""));
                    i.putExtra("post_title", getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_SEL_POST_TITLE));
                    i.putExtra("commentsCount", commentsCount);
                    i.putExtra("user_can_comment", user_can_comment);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1000);
                }
            });

            //Button Click
            Button viewWeb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewWeb);
            if (Const.ShowPostOnExternalBrowser) {
                viewWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        goToUrl(objURL);
                    }
                });
            }


            // Converting timestamp into x ago format
            CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                    Long.parseLong(feedObj.getString("timeStamp")),
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
            timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

            profilePic.setImageUrl(feedObj.getString("profilePic"), imageLoader);


            loadConfig();
            //pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //llayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void goToUrl(String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

    private void loadConfig() {
        if (post_image != null) {
            ViewCompat.setTransitionName(postImageView, TAG_SEL_POST_IMAGE);
            Picasso.with(this).load(post_image).into(postImageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) postImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    new Palette.Builder(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                            applyPalette(palette, postImageView);
                        }
                    });
                    /*Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                            applyPalette(palette, postImageView);
                        }
                    });*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
        } else {
            postImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @JavascriptInterface
    public void resize(final float height) {
        PostViewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trigger: " + height + " // " + (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //post_contentHTML.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        post_contentHTML.loadUrl("javascript:asiannews.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
    }

    public static CharSequence trimTrailingWhitespace(CharSequence source) {

        if (source == null)
            return "";

        int i = source.length();

        // loop back to the first non-whitespace character
        while (--i >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
        }

        return source.subSequence(0, i + 1);
    }

    // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }


    public class URLImageParser implements Html.ImageGetter {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
            // the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
            // with the loading image if you need to
            protected Drawable drawable;

            @Override
            public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
                // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
                if (drawable != null) {
                    drawable.draw(canvas);
                }
            }
        }

        class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
            URLDrawable urlDrawable;

            public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
                this.urlDrawable = d;
            }

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
                String source = params[0];
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(source);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    Picasso pic = new Picasso.Builder(mContext).build();
                    bitmap = pic.load(uri).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
                urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                        + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

                // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
                // from the HTTP call
                urlDrawable.drawable = result;

                // redraw the image by invalidating the container
                URLImageParser.this.mView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        private final Context mContext;
        private final View mView;

        public URLImageParser(Context context, View view) {
            mContext = context;
            mView = view;
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(source);
            URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();
            ImageGetterAsyncTask task = new ImageGetterAsyncTask(urlDrawable);
            task.execute(source);
            return urlDrawable;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(PostViewActivity.this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(PostViewActivity.this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you coded this in native android or just javascript? Please put the code you have written.

Comment: i have coded this in native android.

Comment: In your activity_post_view xml, you can add an admob widget there instead since you have made this from native android. And instantiate it from the corresponding Java Class

Comment: but i cant able to remove the space which is caused due to javascript add in website?

Comment: I have also used ADmob widget in activity_post_view.xml @Mike

Comment: you need to edit the website itself such that when the width is of mobile don't show it. I think media query is the right thing to do here.

Comment: Sir please give me code for the media query/

Comment: I cannot give you a code since it is your website to test the screens you can read more about MediaQuery here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp